# Double value rounding

Tags: c#

Good day,

I've been trying to figure out to manipulate rounding on a double value in the following case:

```
void Main()
{
    var m_MinTemperature = 30d;
    var m_MaxTemperature = 66.9d;

    Console.WriteLine("#1:" + Math.Round(9.15d, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    Console.WriteLine("#2:" + (9.15d).ToString("G17"));
    var r = ToCelcius(m_MinTemperature) + ToCelcius(m_MaxTemperature);
    Console.WriteLine("#3:" + r.ToString("G17")); 
    Console.WriteLine("#4:" + (r / 2d).ToString("G17"));
    Console.WriteLine("#5:" + Math.Round((r / 2d), 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString("G17"));
}

double ToCelcius(double fahrenheit)
{
    return Math.Round((fahrenheit - 32d) / 1.8d, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

The ouput of this is:

> 1:9,2
>
> 2:9,1500000000000004
>
> 3:18,299999999999997
>
> 4:9,1499999999999986
>
> 5:9,0999999999999996

The desired behavior is to round up to only the second decimal, so that 9.15 always round up to 9.2 like in line #1. I was under the impression that using Math.Round with a specified number of digit was taking care of removing the 'trailing' part of the value and that later calculation would be done using double value that were rounded up like in line #2.

Is there any way to achieve this desired behavior? Should I use another type?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Math.Round() on fractional values only has completely predictable behavior on values of type *decimal*.  Never intentionally throw away significant digits, only round the value at the last possible moment.  When you convert it to a string.

Comment: Could you add a couple of cases that don't end with `5`?

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for this bit of information, using decimal seems to work as expected, although using such type might be a little 'overkill', the situation we have justify we could use it for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `decimal` instead of `double`

```
public static void Main()
{
var m_MinTemperature = 30M;
var m_MaxTemperature = 66.9M;

Console.WriteLine("#1:" + Math.Round(9.15M, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
Console.WriteLine("#2:" + (9.15M).ToString("G17"));
var r = ToCelcius(m_MinTemperature) + ToCelcius(m_MaxTemperature);
Console.WriteLine("#3:" + r.ToString("G17")); 
Console.WriteLine("#4:" + (r / 2M).ToString("G17"));
Console.WriteLine("#5:" + Math.Round((r / 2M), 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString("G17"));
}


static decimal ToCelcius(decimal fahrenheit)
{
    return Math.Round((fahrenheit - 32M) / 1.8M, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```

and result is

```
#1:9.2
#2:9.15
#3:18.3
#4:9.15
#5:9.2
```

please see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xflTiT)